# Kinect - What is the direction of the Z axis of a SkeletonPoint

Tags: kinect

I have a very simple question regarding the Z axis of a `SkeletonPoint`. Is the Z value the direct distance to the sensor (the left Z? in the image) or is the Z value the distance to the sensor baseline (the right Z? in the image).

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Z` is the distance from the Kinect's baseline (your right `Z`).  If you could follow left/right path along your `X` axis without gaining or losing distance from the Kinect then `Z` would remain the same.

The coordinate system is a standard [Cartesian coordinate system in 3-dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).